# Symfony submitting form with relationships created at the same time

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form that is related to multiple entities with relations between each other.

As an example I have the following fields:

Name
Surname
Email

Job

Annex

The first 3 are linked with the table called "Candidates"

The Job has its own table "applications" that requires the candidate_id

and Annex has its own table requiring the "application_id"

The problem is that I cannot get those ID's as they are all created at the same time!

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The answer to this question might help - you need to persist the Candidate before you persist the Application, and you need to persist the Application before the Annex.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829948/id-not-saved-in-onetomany-relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the entities and persist them, After you persist an entity you can call getId on it or set the relation, they will be all inserted into database at once when you call flush

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity2= new Entity2();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->persist($entity2);
$entity->setEntity2($entity2);

var_dump($entity->getId());

$em->flush();
```